# Basic QueryBuilder - Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I'm confronted to do a querybuilder (or SQL request) in one of my repository.
Every example I searched are quite complex, and I wanted a basic explanation of a basic QueryBuilder

I have a controller named `RestaurantController`
I have a `RestaurantRepository` where I know I should do my query.

```
class RestaurantRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

}
```

I have my entity called `Restaurant.php` where I have 2 columns(not including the ID one)

- Name
- City

So basically I want to make a query where I can pick up my `city` and then be able to work with that in my view. How can I do that? :/

I created one directly in my controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$restaurants = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Restaurant')->findBy(array('city' => $request->request->get('city')));
```

but this is not working well so I really want to know how to make a proper and simple querybuilder. Thank you

Comment: Step by step? Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'but this is not working', you should check that `$request->request->get('city')` return a valid city name. In your controller, your can do `return var_dump($request->request->get('city')` and verify that you have the expected city. In my opinion, it should be `$request->get('city')`. So basically :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$currentCity = $request->request->get('city') 
return var_dump($currentCity)//make sur that you have a valid city
$restaurants = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Restaurant')->findBy(array('city' => $currentCity));
```

You can make a custom query but it's overkill for your need

```
class RestaurantRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getRestaurantByCity($city)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
                        ->where('r.city = :city')
                        ->setParameter('city', $city)
                          ;

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! thank you very much for your answer! I thought no one would answer me :)
Can you explain me why you put `'r'` in the createQueryBuilder? what does stand for all these punctuations? `= :city`
Also how can I pass this queryBuilder to my view? you wrote `return $query->getQuery()->getResult();` so how can I know and use it in my twig?

Comment: You should really take a look to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder). That said, `'r'` is an alias (you can call it `'bestDevEver'` if you want). `= :city` mean fetch restaurant where the city field is equal to given string. To avoid SQL injection, you create a local variable in the query and assign its value by `setParameter()`. In your twig template, you can access the restaurant properties in for loop by something like `{{ restaurant.city }}`. One advise, you should really follow a tuto or read some docs...

Comment: Thank you, I will try, I read a lot of docs but I always don't know where to start, but thank you for your help. I will apply your answer.